# Does LLDB have convenience variables ($var)?

Tags: lldb

Does LLDB have [convenience variables](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html)? If so, how do I use them? If not, is there anything similar that I can use?

Reference: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/atom/application/debugger/commands143.html

Comment: I don't see any evidence that it does.  Its web site is http://lldb.llvm.org/ and they have mailing lists, perhaps you could ask the maintainers directly.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself. Run `help expr` in LLDB and you will see:

> User defined variables:
>       You can define your own variables for convenience or to be used in subsequent expressions.
>       You define them the same way you would define variables in C.  If the first character of 
>       your user defined variable is a $, then the variable's value will be available in future
>       expressions, otherwise it will just be available in the current expression.

So `expr int $foo = 5` is what I want.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a function to list any variables defined in this fashion during a session? That would be super handy. Something like `expr list`...

Answer (score 32):

I struggled with this today. Here's what it looks like to deal with Objective-C variables in LLDB:

```
expr UIApplication *$app = (UIApplication *)[UIApplication sharedApplication]
expr UIWindow *$keyWindow = (UIWindow *)[$app keyWindow]
```

etc. I've found LLDB works best if you don't nest any calls, and you explicitly give a return type on every call.

Still I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to make `initWithFrame:` work on a UIView later on though. :/

Answer (score 9):

Just use the form:

```
(lldb) expr var
```

From their [tutorial](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html):

> ```
> (lldb) expr self
> $0 = (SKTGraphicView *) 0x0000000100135430
> (lldb) expr self = 0x00
> $1 = (SKTGraphicView *) 0x0000000000000000
> ```
>
> You can also call functions:
>
> ```
> (lldb) expr (int) printf ("I have a pointer 0x%llx.\n", self)
> $2 = (int) 22
> I have a pointer 0x0.
> (lldb) expr self = $0
> $4 = (SKTGraphicView *) 0x0000000100135430
> ```

Answer (score 2):

For swift version

```
e let $data = Data()
```

```
po $data
```

output:

```
▿ 0 bytes
  - count : 0
  ▿ pointer : 0x000000016d36d9d0
    - pointerValue : 6127278544
  - bytes : 0 elements
```